# WiFi setting of iPod touch is cleared

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ipod-touch

At home, I connect my iPod touch to the internet using wi-fi, but often the settings reset themselves back to their defaults.

That means every time i want to use my iPod touch I have to manually re-enter my wi-fi network settings, which is a pain and is a disincentive for using my iPod as often as I would want to.

How can I make my iPod touch remember my wi-fi settings? Is there anyone here willing to help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post on the Apple discussion board](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9070719) provides a solution:

> I have had my 2nd Gen ipod touch
>   (32Gig). I set it up on my wireless
>   network which does not broadcast its
>   SSID and is 128 bit WEP (yeh yeh I
>   know weak) encrypted. This makes for
>   quite a daunting task when forced to
>   type in the WEP key every time the
>   ipod 'forgets' this access points
>   settings.
>
> However I did discover what seems like
>   a quick work-around. I entered the
>   SSID, chose WEP, and for the pass i
>   just entered a bunch of random chars.
>   It said wrong password then connected
>   up to my network fine with the old
>   profile that it appeared to have lost.
>   Not sure if just entering the SSID
>   brought it back to life or not, but
>   it's better than having to manually
>   enter those huge encryption keys.

See also this blog post which points to the message board post above: Tips: [Fix iPhone/iPod touch Losing Wi-Fi Settings](http://www.onemoretap.com/2009/02/28/tips-fix-iphoneipod-touch-losing-wifi-settings/)